# How to bind values to a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to bind data to several dropdownlists and I want to display a text according to the values(code) of it.
This is the code

```
distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "NAT_NAME");
ddlNationality.DataSource = distinctValues;
ddlNationality.DataTextField = "NAT_NAME";
ddlNationality.DataValueField = "NAT_code";
ddlNationality.DataBind();
```

NAT_code contains a number for a nation and NAT_NAME has relevant name of the nation as a text. Query works well when I execute in the sql server. But when I run it the program I get an exception as follows.

```
Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'NAT_code'.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: i think your distinctValues datatable only contain "NAT_NAME" column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `NAT_CODE` field is missing in **columnNames[]** of [View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx). add it to your distinct values. It should be like this.

```
distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "NAT_NAME",  "NAT_code");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.

```
distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "NAT_NAME","NAT_code");
ddlNationality.DataSource = distinctValues;
ddlNationality.DataTextField = "NAT_NAME";
ddlNationality.DataValueField = "NAT_code";
ddlNationality.DataBind();
```

Comment: Why should someone try that without any explanation of your suggested change?